# Reading app that parses and syncs between Mac and iOS

Tags: macos, ios, applications, software-recommendation

I do a lot of proofreading for my job and a lot of reading for pleasure. With that said, I need something that can parse a web page, reflow a PDF, parse text from a .doc, .epub, .txt (and any other document) that also allows me to highlight the text afterwards.

Basically, I need something like Instapaper Pro, except that I'd like it to also be able to reflow PDFs and other documents so that I can highlight and annotate.

Also, it should make the text pleasurable to read (like Readability, Pocket, Instapaper, etc.).

Is there any such reading app out there that exists like this? Ideally, I would just use Evernote, but the highlight functionality is really bad on an iOS device, it doesn't look pretty, and they don't allow you to markup documents on iOS.

Comment: PDFs are different to the others so this is really two or more  questions

Comment: What I mean is I want it to extract the text from the PDF, and put it in a good reading format. Similar to GoodReader's PDF reflow feature, except I don't necessarily need to keep the PDF file format as well. In fact, I don't need it to annotate the PDF at all, just be readable

Comment: What I meant is the answer for a pdf differs from a doc which differs from epub and obviously easy for a .txt - So make it clear what you want